# Crystal reports - What do I need to install to get my website to work without any errors?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, crystal-reports, web

I recently got the task to fix a website that has some errors in it. I have to work with Crystal Reports. However I have no experience with Crystal Reports so far. I work in visual studio 2013 and .Net 4.5. I tried to install it before but I got: 'Could not load file or assembly' errors and was missing a file. So my question to you is: What do I need to install to get my website to work without any errors? (what version etc.)

EDIT: I downloaded and installed the latest version of crystal reports and got this error:

```
Could not load file or assembly
CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Commonls, Version=13.0.2000.0,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its
dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

This is the log:

```
=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Commonls,         Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/School/Vacaturesite/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\School\Vacaturesite\bin
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\School\Vacaturesite\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file:   C:\Users\Beheerder\Documents\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Commonls,  Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304
LOG: Attempting download of new URL   file:///C:/Users/Beheerder/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET   Files/vs/ae77f9fe/8f0f70a0/CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Commonls.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL   file:///C:/Users/Beheerder/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET   Files/vs/ae77f9fe/8f0f70a0/CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Commonls/CrystalDeci     sions.ReportAppServer.Commonls.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL   file:///C:/School/Vacaturesite/bin/CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Commonls.DLL .
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/School/Vacaturesite/bin/CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Commonls/Cry stalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Commonls.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL  file:///C:/Users/Beheerder/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET  Files/vs/ae77f9fe/8f0f70a0/CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Commonls.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL  file:///C:/Users/Beheerder/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET   Files/vs/ae77f9fe/8f0f70a0/CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Commonls/CrystalDeci     sions.ReportAppServer.Commonls.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL  file:///C:/School/Vacaturesite/bin/CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Commonls.EXE .
LOG: Attempting download of new URL  file:///C:/School/Vacaturesite/bin/CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Commonls/CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Commonls.EXE.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to download appropriate runtime (32/64 bit) from this page and install it on server.
[SAP Crystal Reports](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824)

Comment: Do I have to install the newest? (Support Pack 12)

Comment: Every update should fix some issues. I've got latest version installed and so far I haven't experienced any problems.

Comment: Ok, I installed the latest version and immediately got this error while trying to run the website: `Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Commonls, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`

Comment: Ok, one of assembly is missing. But I think you misspelled that assemblyname (not "commonls", but something else).
Since you're woking in Visual Studio, try to remove that reference and add appropriate one.